# Stopping effects from repeating on one another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, effects

I posted this question earlier but I have modified my code to a simple algorithm and I still have the same issue as before:

I created a `picturebox` which, when an effect is selected, it will then change the image in the `picturebox` using the color matrix.

The issues I'm having is if I choose another effect when one is selected the old effect will not disappear, instead it will just stay there and be underneath the new effect selected. The effects I'm using is sepia and greyscale for now, but can anyone help me so that once one effect is selected, the old effect is cleared rather than them just stacking up on one another. "

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to cache the originalImage in a non-volatile area.  For example, load it up into a hidden pictureBox that you don't touch.

When you want to apply an effect, copy the originalImage over into a displayImage `picturebox` and then apply the effect.

Comment: It's pretty easy.  Drop another picturebox onto your form.  Set it's visibility to hidden.  When you load the image from disk, put it in that box first, then copy it to the one you already have that is visible.   When you click the button to apply an effect, first copy the image from this hidden picturebox to your visible one THEN apply the effect to the visible one.

Comment: I believe this is kind of what I am getting at. You aren't setting your original image when you apply an effect. You seem to be setting the image you have already applied the effect too.

Comment: I have edited the code above with the hidden picturebox being called displaypicturebox but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like you are setting your image to the image that is there. I am not sure but this may be taking into account what you have already set. For example when you set

```
Image originalImage = pictureBox.Image;
```

This may be taking the image you have displayed along with any effects you have already applied and setting that as your image to be modified. Like I said I am unsure of this since I can't test it at the moment.

**EDIT**

The following works for me:

Replace

```
Bitmap originalImage = (Bitmap)displayPictureBox.Image;
originalImage = (Bitmap)pictureBox.Image.Clone();
```

With

```
Image therealoriginalimage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testimg.png");
Bitmap originalImage = (Bitmap)therealoriginalimage;
```

As both answers mention it looks like you are setting your original image = what is currently in the picture box.

The above code is a quick fix so you can see exactly what was happening. You should modify this and have the `originalimage` saved as a varible as soon as your app starts. It will be much cleaner than the example above that sets the image each time you call the method

Comment: @T1q234 I removed the portion that was tried and did not work.

Comment: I have edited my code above and i'm still having the same issue

Comment: @T1q234 I have edited my answer. When I run locally I see it going from Gray to Sephia. Unless I am missing something nothing seems to be overlapping.